# How to export fitted curve to 1D vector

Tags: matlab

With the use of `Curve Fitting` toolbox I'm fitting to 11 data points a curve described by a custom equation. As a result I get something like this:

[image]

I want to save 1D vector represented bye the red line on the plot above into a matlab variable. I try to use `Fit->Save to Workspace...` option from the `Curve Fitting` toolbox menu, but saved variables do not contain any of the fitted data.

How can I save fitted data into matlab variable?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Curve Fitting toolbox, but if you click that line, it should become the current object. You can then get the X and Y data.
xData = get(gco, 'xdata');
yData = get(gco, 'ydata');
Then use the save function to save them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The saved MATLAB-object (default name is `fittedmodel`) contains the fitted function as a function-handle and the fitted coefficients corresponding to this function-handle. You can then evaluate at the data points of your choice with `feval`.

In the following example the fitted function will be evaluated at the original datapoints `x`:

```
y = feval(fittedmodel, x);
```

Now you can directly plot the result:

```
plot(x,y);
```